# How Get bitmap from input stream after decode size

Tags: android, bitmap

I want to get bitmap from a inputstream, then resize it. But I am getting null pointer exception.

I try inputstream.reset() but not working.

Can anybody help please?

```
 BufferedInputStream my_is = new BufferedInputStream(is);
                Bitmap    bit           = null;

                final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
                BitmapFactory.decodeStream(my_is, null, options);

                // Calculate inSampleSize
                options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

                // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
                options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

                try {
                    my_is.reset();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                bit     = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(my_is, null, options);

                String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",
                        Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
                FileOutputStream fos = null;
                try {
                    fos = getActivity().openFileOutput(timeStamp + ".png", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    bit.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,90,fos);
                    fos.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                crud.update_photo_path(String.valueOf(position), timeStamp);

                return bit;
```

Comment: Why reread from the stream when you already have the `Bitmap` and you can just resize it? `Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(largeBitmap, h, w, true);`

Answer (score 0):

I used this utils:

```
public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(String uri,
        int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(uri, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth,
            reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(uri, options);
}

private static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options,
        int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
        if (width > height) {
            inSampleSize = Math.round((float) height / (float) reqHeight);
        } else {
            inSampleSize = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);
        }
    }
    return inSampleSize;
}
```

Comment: BitmapFactory.decode file function is working but BitmapFactory.decodeStream () function not working